# Converting Promise to non promise in module export

Tags: javascript

Is there any way a non async function can return the resolved Promise value? Or for async to return non Promise?

I have a module A that I want to import dynamically in module B. Since it's dynamical it produces a promise. From module B I would like to expose part of it (the resolved part of `adapterPromise`) as a non Promise object.

```
const foo = async () => {
  return await adapterPromise;
};

export const MyAdapter = () => foo(); // I don't want this to be a Promise
```

The problem I run into is that since `foo` is async, then it always produces a `Promise` and I'd like to avoid that (the reason is that `MyAdapter` consists of functions that I want to call repeatedly and as far as I know, the same Promise shouldn't be resolved multiple times).

It is possible to do this with Top level await

```
export default await adapterPromise;
```

I'm curious if this is the only way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Why not call those functions in `MyAdapter` after the promise resolves?

Comment: @tevemadar I think your link talked more generally about how to use Promises, but didn't really address how I wanted to use it.

Comment: @Ivar I believe that requires additional safe guarding against too early calls which makes it more complex. However, I can't see a better way to it might be the best way forward.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to `return` the Promise value. But you can definitely use it in a callback function

```
function foo (callback) {
  var p = ...; // a promise
  p.then(function(a) {
    callback(a);
  });
}
```

Comment: My scenario is to return object which whose methods will be called multiple times, so I don't think this approach is applicable (I don't have a single callback to call once promise is resolved).

Comment: @user1335014 just combine your callbacks into a single function. This is the only other way besides using await

Comment: It still wouldn't work, the functions are being called elsewhere at various times, some behind user interactions (so there is no way to define a single callback). There is a service behind this adapter, my goal was to initialize this service and make it available at all times.